# refactoring conditional statement

Tags: php, if-statement, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I been trying to find a better way of writing:

This works but there must be a cleaner way right?

```
public static function checkCourierCountry($courier, $country)
{
    if (isset(self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups']['europe']) &&
        in_array($country, self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups']['europe'])) {
        return true;
    }
    if (isset(self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups']['fedex']) &&
        in_array($country, self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups']['fedex'])) {
        return true;
    }
    if (isset(self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups']['parcelForce']) &&
        in_array($country, self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups']['parcelForce'])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - can I ask why your passing courier in?

Answer (score 1):

If `self::shippingGroups()` has any significant computational cost to run (like a database hit), you don't want to be calling it potentially three times. Call it once and store it in a variable. And any time you have repeated hunks of code that look the same, you can probably replace it with a loop:

```
$groups = self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups'];
foreach (['europe', 'fedex', 'parcelForce'] as $group) {
    if (array_key_exists($group, $groups) && in_array($country, $groups[$group])) {
        return true;
    }
}   
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by performing the `shippingGroups()` method call only once and storing the result to a variable. The checks then become much more terse and readable.

```
public static function checkCourierCountry($courier, $country)
    {
        //set var
        $groups = self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups'];
        if (isset($groups['europe']) && in_array($country, $groups['europe'])) {
            return true;
        }
        if (isset($groups['fedex']) && in_array($country, $groups['fedex'])) {
            return true;
        }
        if (isset($groups['parcelForce']) && in_array($country, $groups['parcelForce'])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function checkCourierCountry($courier, $country)
{
    $available = ['europe', 'fedex', 'parcelForce' ];
    foreach($available as $location)
        if (isset(self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups'][$location]) &&
            in_array($country, self::shippingGroups()['shippingGroups'][$location]))
                return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop and cache the shipping groups:

```
public static function checkCourierCountry($country) {
    $shippingGroups = self::shippingGroups();
    $groups = array('europe', 'fedex' , 'parcelForce');
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        if (isset($shippingGroups['shippingGroups'][$group]) && in_array($country, $shippingGroups['shippingGroups'][$group])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```